# How do I test `rand()` with RSpec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I have a method that does something like this:

```
def some_method
  chance = rand(4)
  if chance == 1 do
    # logic here
  else
    # another logic here
  end
end
```

When I use RSpec to test this method, `rand(4)` inside it always generates 0. I am not testing `rand` method of Rails, I am testing my method.
What is a common practice to test my method?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are two approaches I would consider:

***Approach 1***:

Use a known value of seed in `srand( seed )` in a `before :each` block:

```
before :each do
  srand(67809)
end
```

This works across Ruby versions, and gives you control in case you want to cover particular combinations. I use this approach a lot - thinking about it, that's because the code I was testing uses `rand()` primarily as a data source, and only secondarily (if at all) for branching. Also it gets called a lot, so exerting call-by-call control over returned values would be counter-productive, I would end up shovelling in lots of test data that "looked random", probably generating it in the first place by calling `rand()`!

You may wish to call your method multiple times in at least one test scenario to ensure you have reasonable coverage of combinations.

***Approach 2:***

If you have branch points due to values output from `rand()` and your assertions are of the type "if it chooses X, then Y should happen", then it is also reasonable in the same test suite to mock out `rand( n )` with something that returns the values you want to make assertions about:

```
 require 'mocha/setup'

 Kernel.expects(:rand).with(4).returns(1)
 # Now run your test of specific branch
```

In essence these are both "white box" test approaches, they both require you to know that your routine uses `rand()` internally.

A "black box" test is much harder - you would need to assert that behaviour is statistically OK, and you would also need to accept a very wide range of possibilities since valid random behaviour could cause phantom test failures.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6077725/ruby-using-rand-in-code-but-writing-tests-to-verify-probabilities

Answer (score 15):

I'd extract the random number generation:

```
def chance
  rand(4)
end

def some_method
  if chance == 1 do
    # logic here
  else
    # another logic here
  end
end
```

And stub it:

```
your_instance.stub(:chance) { 1 }
```

This doesn't tie your test to the implementation details of `rand` and if you ever decide to use another random number generator, your test doesn't break.

Answer (score 12):

It seems that best idea is to use stub, instead of real `rand`. This way you would be able to test all values that you are interested in. As `rand` is defined in `Kernel` module you should stub it using:

```
Kernel.stub(:rand).with(anything) { randomized_value }
```

In particular contexts you can define `randomized_value` with `let` method.

Comment: I think this is a nice solution. I suggest a minor improvement: `Kernel.stub(:rand).with(anything) { randomized_value }`

Comment: Thanks! Forgot about optional argument.

Comment: Or temporarily turn `rand` into an enumerator if there are multiple code paths and each needs to be tested.

Comment: @theTinMan this solution seems superior, as fact which random value is mapped to which execution path should be implementation detail.

Comment: Using the new rspec syntax this is equivalent to `allow(Kernel).to receive(:rand).and_return(0.5)`

Answer (score 6):

I found that just stubbing rand ie. using Kernel.stub(:rand) as answered by Samuil did not initially work.  My code to be tested called rand directly e.g

> random_number = rand

However, if I changed the code to

> random_number = Kernel.rand

then the stubbing worked.

Answer (score 1):

This works in RSpec:

```
allow_any_instance_of(Object).to receive(:rand).and_return(1)
```