# Get secure random value in rspec

Tags: rspec

In my controller, after downloading xls file that will be redirect to the some location. redirect path contains the securerandom value. How can I get random value as same as to the controller random value.

I have tried by getting random value from spec/controller file. But that value different from the controller value.

This is my controller

```
def xls_job

  ref = SecureRandom.hex

  redirect_to polymorphic_url([:xls_job, :client, booking_type.tableize], { job_id: @job.id, job_ref: ref } )

end
```

I got error like this

```
Expected response to be a redirect to 
<http://test.host/client/interpretings/xls_job?job_id=15433&job_ref=1db823fef6b892e6c1cc362bf8fe5e87> 

but was a redirect to 
<http://test.host/client/interpretings/xls_job?job_id=15433&job_ref=b8c9464466b90e65492627b77e121346>.
```

How can i get random value same as to the controller..?

Comment: Can you show your test code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to stub your `ref` variable like below:

```rb
before { allow(SecureRandom).to receive(:hex).and_return('myrandomhex89809') }
```

source: [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38370512/stub-random-value-in-rspec-with-secure-random)

Should do the trick.