# Rspec/capybara - test presence of a class OR another class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, capybara

In my ruby on Rails 4.2 app, on a page I have a conditional back end rule that translates into the page front end in a change in class

```
<div id="content">
    <i class='<% if x=true %>glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-down<% else> glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up ><% end %>' </i>
       this is the message.
</div>
```

How to check presence with rspec 3/capybara that the page contains the class glyphicon-thumbs-down OR the class glyphicon-thumbs-up ?

I tried the code below but it fails:

```
it "should sheck one of the 2 classes presence" do
  expect(page).to have_css '.glyphicon-thumbs-down' || expect(page).to have_css '.glyphicon-thumbs-up'
end
```

I am getting the following error message:

```
syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError)
```

Comment: Shouldn't you rather prepare the test including the backend rule, so that you know precisely which class will be rendered on the page?

Comment: nope as it's a random rule on the back end (it's game of luck) so i can't predict it inside my test suite

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Multiple OR-ed css selectors can be specified separated by a comma. Try the following:

```
it "should sheck one of the 2 classes presence" do
  expect(page).to have_css '#content i.glyphicon-thumbs-down,#content i.glyphicon-thumbs-up'
end
```

(I added the `#content` and `i` selectors so that the query is more specific.)

However, instead of doing this I would recommend trying to make the test behave in a precisely defined way and test for just a single class in the spec. Have a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17195267/how-do-i-test-rand-with-rspec) and its answers for various ways to stub or preset the random number generator in tests.

Answer (score 7):

Firstly, you're checking for a class name so you need a `.` in front of the class names to make it a CSS class selector. Then, you could use the RSpec `or` matcher combinator

```
expect(page).to have_css('.glyphicon-thumbs-down').or(have_css '.glyphicon-thumbs-up')
```

but it has the downside of the first one retrying/waiting for `Capybara.default_max_wait_time` seconds before checking the second.  You could specify a 0/false wait time if you know the page is already loaded and therefore don't need retrying/waiting

```
 expect(page).to have_css('.glyphicon-thumbs-down', wait: false).or(have_css '.glyphicon-thumbs-up', wait: false)
```

However, it's probably fine to just check for either element using the normal CSS `,`

```
 expect(page).to have_css('.glyphicon-thumbs-down, .glyphicon-thumbs-up')
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, I gave the points to Borama as his suggestion matched the one I needed (your last suggestion) 2 minutes before:) Indeed i must wait for server ajax response and can't use the 0 wait time, so the bets is to first wait_for_ajax then have_css('.glyphicon-thumbs-down, .glyphicon-thumbs-up')

Comment: @Mathieu You shouldn't need `wait_for_ajax` at all there, the `have_css` will wait for one of the two selectors to match (up to Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds)

Comment: i wait for ajax because i have a ajax request sent to server to check a data and send it back to the view. I know have_css will wait...but sometimes in my specific situation i had to use wait_for_ajax to work. Thanks though for the additional positively watchful information

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to use option :count, in expect method like this:

```
it 'should contains 2 same selector' do
  expect(page).to have_css '.some-class', count: 2
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error is from this line:

```
  expect(page).to have_css 'glyphicon-thumbs-down' || expect(page).to have_css 'glyphicon-thumbs-up'
```

You just need to add some parens then it will be valid syntax:

```
expect(page).to(have_css('glyphicon-thumbs-down')) || expect(page).to(have_css('glyphicon-thumbs-up'))
```

that won't fix your issue though, because if the left condition fails then rspec will exit and not run the second half.

A working approach could be to evaluate the condition to a boolean variable, then pass it to a single rspec expectation. Doing this requires using the core Capybara method [has_css](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FNode%2FMatchers:has_css%3F) to test for css presence, not [have_css?](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/Capybara%2FRSpecMatchers%3Ahave_css) from the rspec matchers package:

```
selectors = ['.glyphicon-thumbs-down', '.glyphicon-thumbs-up']
glyph_exists = selectors.any? do |selector|
  page.has_css? selector
end
expect(glyph_exists).to be true
```

Note also that I've added `.` to the selector strings which is necessary since it's a css class.

Comment: This has the downside of each call to `has_css?` waiting Capybara.default_max_wait_time seconds before checking the next one if it doesn't match.

Comment: True. To work around that ive wrapped them in an explicit wait of a very short duration and rescued the error to return false. Not ideal though